# Python parameter error not passing the correct information

Tags: python

I am having an issue with passing and calling my functions. I am not sure why I can't access the string in my parameter, string currently in my code is 1, and number is 0. I would like the string to be whatever I passed  and number to be 1. Any ideas on what I miss. appreciate very much!
Here is the original problem I am trying to solve:

The count-and-say sequence is the sequence of integers with the first five terms as following:

1. 1
2. 11
3. 21
4. 1211
5. 111221
   1 is read off as "one 1" or 11.
   11 is read off as "two 1s" or 21.
   21 is read off as "one 2, then one 1" or 1211.

Given an integer n where 1 ≤ n ≤ 30, generate the nth term of the count-and-say sequence. You can do so recursively, in other words from the previous member read off the digits, counting the number of digits in groups of the same digit.

Note: Each term of the sequence of integers will be represented as a string.
The Parameter passed now n = 1

```
class Solution:
    def recursion_test(self, string, number):
        self.number = number
        print(string)
        print (number)
        iterative_string=''
        count = 1
        loop_num = 0
        if number == 0:
            return string
        else:
            while loop_num < len(string)-1:
                if string[count] == string[count+1]:
                    count +=1
                elif string[count]!= string[count+1]:
                    iterative_string=iterative_string+count+string[count]
                    count=0
                loop+=1
                print(iterative_string)
            number -=1
            return(self.recursion_test(iterative_string, number))

    def countAndSay(self, n: int) -> str:
        return_string =''
        self.recursion_test(return_string, n)
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is the function supposed to do? Where is the code that actually creates a `Solution` and uses the method?

Comment: Karl, I have added more background and hope that helps, It is generating in leetcode, so I am sure it calls it somewhere within their website.

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve], this isn't a leetcode support website. It is unclear exactly what your issue is. You must provide an adequate problem specification, again, with a corresponding [mcve]